# What are the features/technologies that native apps in iOS can use that web apps can't?

Tags: objective-c, ios, html, mobile

I'm struggling trying to figure out if I should go native or if I should go with the web app approach for a particular project. I understand the benefits and the differences in approaches. The biggest question in my mind is what do I lose access to by going with a web app versus going with a native app?

I know there are certain things WebKit can handle that used to be the domain of native apps only (i.e. access to geolocation information). I also know about different frameworks for adding this functionality, like PhoneGap. I'm not looking for any hybrid applications. I'm talking about differences between an app that runs inside Safari and one that is native Obj-C.

Preferably, this will be iOS information and not Android information, but either would be interesting.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as I was looking for a specific list of things that specific to web apps and specific to native apps. It's a very specific question and matches with the general tone and feel of the SO site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Core Data (data storage on the device)
- Camera (except with custom tweaking)
- Accelerometer
- Ability to run and at least provide some UI when no internet
  connection is available
- The iOS App Store distribution method
- Web Apps have to go to the server for everything (UI, data, etc). 
  Native apps only need to go for fresh data and authentication.  This
  usually results in a slower and more clumsy user experience.
- TableViews and ViewControllers (the MVC model)

I am sure there are more.  I was in the same dilemma as you about a year ago.  I decided to take the plunge and learn objective-c so I could do it natively.  I found that the extra time taken to do that was made up for by the ease at which the UI can be generated natively.  The positioning and rendering is so precise and cuts down on the trial and error methods that are usually used when laying out HTML and CSS.

I am glad I did that, I can now crank out a fully functional, complex web-service fed app in a weekend and I need minimal help from my graphics artist to do it.

Comment: MobileSafari supports HTML5 data storage (more limited than Core Data, of course)

Comment: HTML5 supports the Deviceorientation API, so accessing the Accelerometer is no problem

Comment: @Gotschi - Does that include acceleration rate?  I thought that could only tell you the orientation of the device (which is only one small part of what the accelerometer will give you)

Comment: @ElJay yes, see the [DeviceMotionEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceMotionEventClassRef/DeviceMotionEvent/DeviceMotionEvent.html) and [DeviceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/DeviceOrientationEvent/DeviceOrientationEvent.html) classes

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is pretty powerful for webapps, but there are still some APIs missing in the browsers - such as getting access to camera and microphone (the Device/getUserMedia API is still in draft). You can play audio stuff, use accelerometer, gyroscope, geolocation and websockets, but all of this is handled via javascript. This is not bad, but it depends on the browser and its features.

In a native app you can use all of those sensors, but you will have to implement these features explicitly for every desired platform (iOS/Android/WinMO).
And you can use graphic languages (OpenGL) in native applications / WebGL isn't yet supported on mobile devices (afaik). Native apps can use the full potential of the hardware, webapps are limited to their browser's javascript performance.

Answer (score 0):

Web apps (or apps that run on the browser (webKit Engine)) are limited access to the underlying device functionality due to security concerns.. 
So they cannot access many of of the underlying device functionalities like - 
- accessing device contact list and other sensitive information stored in the device
- access to device hardware - like sensors / bluetooth / wifi etc
- make use of underlying OS API calls.

So depending on your application features you will have to device the best for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Native apps can use pre-compiled pre-optimized native ARM code, and the benefits that developer driven compilation provides.  Apps that require significant computation (game physics, audio DSP, etc.) will have better performance, either due to lack of interpreter overhead, more compiler optimization, or not requiring communication overhead and latency of offloading the task to a remote server.  Native code virtual reality creation and similar types of real-time feedback may also have less lag.  The lesser processor cycles or communication needs arising from a natuve code solution might also consume significantly less of the user's limited battery life.

Certain iOS subview animations are only possible or run more smoothly from the native code API than from JavaScript.

User privacy and security concerns may also limit or completely restrict access to certain user data and sensors (photo album, mic, front camera) from Safari web apps, to which native apps currently have some access.